# Is it possible to make a scooter that is propelled by perpetual magnets (without converting it to electricity)?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation, perpetual-motion

I am, along with two of my classmates, are planning to make a prototype of a scooter (as in slower, smaller version of a motorcycle) that is propelled by an infinitely turning magnet wheel. Not as a motor or something that converts the motion to electricity, but as an independently perpetual motion-machine that may lead to the movement of the wheels of the scooter. But we have no blueprint or any plan on how to make that happen. Other than this, we are completely clueless on how to make brakes for this type of thing, how to control the speed, and how will generally work as a whole. We're eighth grade students and are probably going to never have a proper research if this doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to make a scooter that works, you're gonna have to input energy in it, and transform in some way into kinetic energy (i.e. speed). Making an intricate magnet configuration will never work, because no energy is being put inside your system.

Comment: If you only want to go downhill it might work...

Comment: If perpetual motion was possible, do you really think we would still be using petrol/diesel engines?

Answer (score 1):

According to the first and second [laws of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_thermodynamics), there can be no [perpetual motion machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion).Your magnet wheel seems to be intended to provide limitless energy from nothing, which would be a perpetual motion machine of the first kind which is not possible according to the principle of energy conservation described in the first law of thermodynamics.